# My .htaccess files "Save As" .htaccess.htaccess. Is that normal?Does it effect my PHP in codeigniter?

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter

This occurs in Sublime Text 2 and Wordpad, Notepad. I have been fighting to remove index.php from my URLs and I wondered if this might be the problem, I'm new. Thanks.

Comment: You should save it as ".htaccess".

Comment: (which means literally, including the quotes)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it will affect your codeigniter setup - your mod_rewrite rules won't be picked up unless the file is called .htaccess, and so the index.php won't be removed like you want it to.

I would fix this by going into a terminal/command prompt, go to the directory where the .htaccess.htaccess file is and renaming the file there.

If you are using windows, you do this with the command (once you are in the correct directory)

```
rename .htaccess.htaccess .htaccess
```